# Git Laravel - what should I do if I change files in the vendor directory?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've changed the authenticatesUser trait located in the vendor folder.

Them changes are not tracked so when pulling the project, the login features won't work.

Should i just track the whole of vendor?

or create a new file outside of vendor to handle the authenticatesUser trait?

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever track `/vendor`.
Never, ever edit `/vendor` files.

You're asking the wrong question. Your question should be, "I want to change this default functionality on this Illuminate code. How do I do this without overwriting `/vendor` files?" You'd also need to present the code you'd need to change.

99% of the time you can get the functionality you want be overriding the default. For instance, if I inherit a trait that defines the function "doSomething", but I need it to work differently, at best you can do this:

```
public function doSomething()
{
    $this->doSomethingElse();
    return parent::doSomething();
}
```

That inserts my functionality inside the function then calls the vendor logic. Or, I can omit `parent::doSomething()` and completely override it. if you really need to, you can copy the source code and change it to flavor without ever touching `/vendor`.

Comment: I was also doing the same. I edited the authenticateUser in the vendor folder but it was not tracking in git. Then i did some research and found that we are not supposed to edit the vendor file, but you can override the methods in your classes. That is a safer option. I had to override couple of methods and it worked fine.

Comment: I have a bit different problem. I had composer installed a php sdk on my laravel project. But it didn't work for one part. So I have to change that part of code. But since vendor is not tracking in git, I don't know what to do.
Please advice me @Josh.